# Filter predicate count with Spring Data

Tags: java, sql, spring-data

I am building a Java Spring MVC webapp with a Spring Data Backend. In my app you can search for articles or for categories. Later on you can refine the search results with further filter predicates like color, size and so on. I was wondering how it is possible to add the total to every predicate like autoscout24.com does.

Example:

searched article: Sneaker
searched category: Shoes

Refine your search:

Color:
red (1.001)
green (453)
black (12.000)

Size:
8 (1.000)
9 (2.000)
10 (10.021)

That means that there are 1.000 sneakers in size 8 available. If I select red, the total number of size 8 shoes will decrease as well because not all size 8 shoes are red. 
I am using Pageable in my Query because I don't want to load thousands of articles at once from database. That means the counting cannot be done in the result list. It would not be scalable as well. Or is this made by using a second query with multiple counts? How can I use this with Spring Data? Is it possible or do I have to use a native query?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build a custom query and use `SELECT colorName, count(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY colorName`.

The other way would be to use a `count(*)` query for every attribute, i.e.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE colorName = 'red';
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE colorName = 'green';
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE colorName = 'black';
```

The same for sizes. But this might be slower than `GROUP BY`.

---

### Alternative (faster, but more complex):

create an additional table, which acts as some kind of key value store, where you save precomputed values:

```
type | name | amount
--------------------
COLOR| red  | 1001
COLOR| green| 453
COLOR| black| 12000
SIZE | 8    | 1000
SIZE | 9    | 2000
SIZE | 10   | 10021
```

When ever an item gets created/updated/deleted, you must also update the table with the precomputed values.

You could also store much more complex things like "amount of combination 'color=green' & 'size=9'". It's always a simple `amount = amount+1` or `amount = amount-1`.

This way it's super fast to retrieve the values, but you've got to maintain an additional table.

---

I know, that this answer is not really related to Spring Data, but there's not really much Spring Data can do for you in this case. The logic you're expecting must be hand crafted, Spring Data can only execute the queries for you and map the results to some POJO.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will give the second part a try. Since I fill my database by batch importing csv files anyway, I can fill this new amount table as well. I think it would be smart if the combinations of filter predicates are stored during the import. E.G. if there is a red article in size 8 and there is no other one yet, I will insert the combination "COLOR&SIZE" with "red&8" and amount = 1 to datatable if there is an entry already I will increase the amount. Nice! Thank you.

Comment: If you insert "red & 8", then you should do `red++`, `8++` and `red&8++`, because the article belongs to all three categories. Also make sure to specify a concrete ordering of the attributes (maybe simply by alphabet of the category names), because if the user searches for `color=red` + `size=8` and `price=300` you must know that you're looking for `red&300&8` (because **c**olor < **p**rice < **s**ize) and not for `300&8&red`. Additionally you might also need to think about multi-valued attributes - i.e. what if an article can have multiple colors, etc.. just ask if you need more information.

Comment: hey thanks! I will ask you if there are more questions to come!